# Dynamically reallocating an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, realloc

A part of my code will read in an unknown number of lines from a text file, parse that line into a structure (tempSomeStruct), resize the SomeStruct_Array, and then add that tempSomeStruct into the newly opened spot in memory.

However after a few times through the while loop, my program stops and says

> myApplication.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I did not set a breakpoint, and doing some digging, it LOOKS like the breakpoint is due to heap corruption from my call to realloc.  I am pretty new to dynamic allocation, so while I have searched and found a few possible causes, so far no fixes have worked.

How am I corrupting the heap in this situation, and what do I do differently to avoid doing so?

I have a function like this:

```
int growArray(SomeStruct **SomeStruct_Array,int currentSize, int numNewElements)
{
    const int totalSize = currentSize + numNewElements;
    SomeStruct *temp = (SomeStruct*)realloc(*SomeStruct_Array,(totalSize * sizeof(SomeStruct)));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate more memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *SomeStruct_Array = temp;
    }

    return totalSize;
}
```

and it is called in elsewhere like this:

```
SomeStruct* SomeStruct_Array = (SomeStruct *) calloc(1,sizeof(SomeStruct));
int Error_Array_Size = 0;

if(SomeStruct_Array == NULL)
{
   printf("Cannot allocate initial memory for data\n");
   return;
}

while(fgets(line,sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
   parseTextIntoSomeStruct(line, &tempSomeStruct);
   SomeStruct_Array_Size = growArray(&SomeStruct_Array,SomeStruct_Array_Size,1);
   if(SomeStruct_Array_Size > 0)
   {
      SomeStruct_Array[SomeStruct_Array_Size] = tempSomeStruct;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new array's size is `SomeStruct_Array_Size`, and you immediately write to `SomeStruct_Array[SomeStruct_Array_Size]` which is one past the end of the array! Remember, C arrays are zero-indexed.

Use

```
SomeStruct_Array[SomeStruct_Array_Size-1] = tempSomeStruct;
```

instead.

Comment: I added something to my code that I neglected in this sample, I initialize the size to 0, and I already had 1 space allocated before I even assigned the someStruct there.  So it should have been a valid array location.

Comment: No, still incorrect. Your `realloc` creates an array of size exactly `totalSize`, and you return `totalSize`. So, the array has exactly `SomeStruct_Array_Size` after `realloc`, not one more.

Comment: Ohh.... I see, so for my first run through the loop, since my initialization was incorrect (saying the size was 0 when it was really 1), I just ended up reallocating the area i already allocated to the same size.  As such I was then writing to SomeStruct_Array[1] when it only still goes as high as SomeStruct_Array[0].  I thought this error was a bit more advanced than a simple "Off by one" error.